# Why isn't my mvc ajax not finding the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using a  to call an API action through a $ajax call, but it doesn't seem to be calling the api at all, and when the button is clicked, the fail message just comes up. What am I missing/doing wrong?
Here is the View and the embedded ajax:

> ```
>           <a href="@Url.Action("SingleOrderView","Cailz", new{ ID = item.ID})">View</a>
>                 <a href="#" class="js-refuse-order" data-order-id="@item.ID">Refuse</a>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </li>
> </ul> } @section scripts
> {
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $(".js-refuse-order").click(function (e) {
>             var link = $(e.target);
>             if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to refuse this order?")) {
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: "/api/cailz/" + link.attr("data-order-id"),
>                     method: "POST"
>                 })
>                 .done(function () {
>                     link.parents("li").fadeOut(function () {
>                         $(this).remove();
>                     });
>                 })
>                 .fail(function () {
>                     alert("Something went wrong " + link.attr("data-order-id"))
>                 });
>             }
>         })
>     })
> </script>
> ```

And here is the related API:

```
 using CailzMk2.DataLayer; 
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using CailzMk2.Models;

 namespace CailzMk2.API 
 {
     [Authorize]
     public class CailzController : ApiController
     {
         private ApplicationDbContext _context;

         public CailzController()
         {
             _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
         }

         [HttpPost]
         public IHttpActionResult Refuse(int id)
         {
             var refusedOrder = _context.Orders.Single(o => o.ID == id);
             refusedOrder.OrderRefused = true;
             _context.SaveChanges();
             return Ok();
         }
     } 
 }
```

I've been struggling with this for some time.

The Function is called with a button press, and the correct ID does come through.  All I can think of is that it can't find it.

And here is a the route Config, just the default configuration:

```
namespace CailzMk2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL (in the Ajax call) appears to be incorrect as it doesn't have the action component. It should be something like this:

```
url: "/api/Cailz/Refuse/" + link.attr("data-order-id"), 
method: "POST"
```

Also, you should use `[HttpPost]` on the action instead of `[HttpDelete]` for consistency.

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried before I posted.  I tried it again, and it still didn't go through.

Comment: What exactly did you try: changing to `[HttpPost] ` or changing the URL? The URL is more important and if it's not hitting your action, then you need to check what Routing is doing. My answer assumes that the relevant routing is the default that comes when MVC project is created; ie, `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: Yes, the URL.  I also checked the routing, which should comply with the routing that I used.  I was using the default routing.

Comment: And your method is marked `[HttpPost] ` just like your Ajax is marked POST?  If Yes, then you may need to share the class where your routes are registered so we can take a look.

Comment: Cool. From your routing config, you will need to remove `/api` from your  URL in the Ajax call. It's not needed.

Comment: It should be ` url: "/Cailz/Refuse/" + link.attr("data-order-id"), `

Comment: Changed the URL as suggested, still didn't work.  Moved the API contoller into the controller folder to simplify the routing, still didn't work.  Totally at a loss now...

Comment: It seems you've tinkered with a lot. Now, what URL is the Ajax trying to access? You can find out by pressing F12 on your browser and checking Network tab. Who knows, it might even be that your Ajax is not even firing.

Comment: I'm getting a 404, and PostMan interceptor shows that the ajax is firing, sending off this:
POSThttp://localhost:50848/Cailz/Refuse/11

Comment: Everything looks fine @JoshOgden from what you've shared so far, and there's no reason to keep having the problem, from the code you've shared. I don't think the issue is from your code - unless you didn't build after the last set of modifications. You can do an `iisreset` or kill `w3wp`; then start afresh.